# setting values from an json array to spinner on application level

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to set Json values into a spinner list. The data I have:

```
JSONArray lang = jsonObject.getJSONArray("languages");

for (int i = 0; i < lang.length(); i++) {
    String language = lang.getString(i);
}
```

How can i load String values into a spinner list?

Comment: by using the adapter ... seriously, there is a plenty tutorials out there ...

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(yourContext, android.R.layout.activity_list_item)
arrayAdapter.addAll(langList); // you need to add your lang.getString(i) to an array
yourSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

and voila!

Comment: But how to pass these values... and fetch in another activity one by one.. ??

Comment: I've answered this question in my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your problem, you have list of records and you want to show them in spinner in multiple activity.
For this you can create an Class that extends Application Class and create a list in that class.

once You receive response from you web api set data in list of application class.

Now where ever you want to display data in Spinner get it from Application class and render your spinner

See below Example -

```
public class MyApp extends Application{

   private static ArrayList<String> mDataArrayList;

   public static ArrayList<String> getmDataArrayList() {
      return mDataArrayList;
   }
   public static void setmDataArrayList(ArrayList<String> mDataArrayList) {
       MyApp.mDataArrayList = mDataArrayList;
   }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
    }

  }
```

Call your web api and parse data as you code in your question -

```
       ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
       for (int i = 0; i < lang.length(); i++) {
             String language = lang.getString(i);
             mArrayList.add(language);
        }
       //Set Application class list
           MyApp.setmDataArrayList(mArrayList);
```

Now when you want to display data in any class then get list by calling -

```
ArrayList<String> mArrayList = MyApp.getmDataArrayList();
//Code to display data in Spinner
```

Hope it will help you.

And dont forgot to add it to manifest of your application -

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name=".MyApp"
    ....>
   ....
  </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use Spinner class activity for future usages. Here is the example of spinner activity class (data receiver and displayer):

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class mySpinnerClass extends Activity implements
        OnItemSelectedListener {

    Spinner spinner;

    int selectedValue;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spinner);
        selectedValue = -1;

        Intent i = getIntent();
        dataSelector = i.getStringExtra("MessageText");

        // Spinner element
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);

        // Spinner click listener
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        // Loading spinner data
        loadSpinnerData();
    }

    private void loadSpinnerData() {

        // Spinner Drop down elements
        List<String> lables = yourData.get(dataSelector);

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }


    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        //get the label and do anything you want with it
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

In caller activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), mySpinnerClass.class);
 i.putExtra("MessageText",yourData);
 startActivity(i);
```

If you want to send non-primitive data (in your example, this is a list) you need to use Serializable type while sending and receiving it. The following link illustrates this technique well:

http://javatechig.com/android/pass-a-data-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android